# No module named 'pandas_datareader' in Jupyter (Anaconda) after I run pip3 install pandas_datareader

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, installation, anaconda, pandas-datareader

I am trying to learn pandas and want to load some stocks data. I was following a course which advised me to load pandas.io.data, but this did not work as io.data was depreciated. So I decided to use pandas-datareader instead. But I am struggling to instal it on mac in Anaconda (Jupiter notebook).

First time I run import pandas_datareader as pdweb I got ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas_datareader'. Not surprising as I never used this before so I run pip3 install pandas_datareader in Terminal which successfully installed itself. However, Jupiter notebook is still giving me the same error. At this point, I tried running in Terminal conda install -c https://conda.anaconda.org/anaconda pandas-datareader but it did not work as -bash: conda: command not found.

Please help. I am looking for a detailed explanation as I am not too techie.

What I run in Jupiter

```
import numpy as np
from pandas import Series, DataFrame
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader as pdweb 
import datetime
```

Result

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-da568f513c93> in <module>
      2 from pandas import Series, DataFrame
      3 import pandas as pd
----> 4 import pandas_datareader as pdweb
      5 import datetime

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas_datareader'
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just run

```
conda install -c anaconda pandas-datareader
```

as per instructions [here](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/pandas-datareader).

In my experience, if you're using conda, you should **never install** with pip unless you're sure conda doesn't have it. Try searching anaconda.org to see which `-c` source to use.

Comment: Thanks. This did work but only after I uninstalled and reinstalled later version of Anaconda.

Comment: Glad it worked. Just a sidenote that you can uninstall Anaconda by following the OS-specific instructions [here](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/uninstall/). Third-party apps are fine in principle, but a lot of them contain malware or spyware, and they sometimes leave behind traces of the program.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with conda command not being set up during the installation of Anaconda. I solved this by removing Anaconda with App Cleaner & Uninstaller Pro (free soft) and reinstalling later version.

After reinstallation of Anaconda command below worked like a charm.

```
conda install -c anaconda pandas-datareader
```

Answer (score 0):

If you using Anaconda and still have issues installing panads-datareader using the conda command 'conda install -c anaconda pandas-datareader'. or the installation is successful but the import pandas_datareader.data as web still gives an error.

Locate where your 'site-packages % ' directory and cd to the site-packages % dir and then run the installation command 'conda install -c anaconda pandas-datareader '. It will work.

Answer (score 0):

First uninstall datareader using below command:

```
pip uninstall pandas_datareader
```

Then install using command:

```
conda install pandas-datareader
```

This is what worked for me!!

Answer (score -1):

For the install, try using

```
pip
```

instead of

```
pip3
```