# Module Not found Error, but cmd says it's already installed

Tags: python, windows

I was trying to run the following command to get some finance data online:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas_datareader import data
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn 
import plotly.express as px

gol_df = data.DataReader(name = 'GOLL4.SA', data_source = 'yahoo', start='2015-01-01')
```

But before I could proceed I got the error listed below;

```
In [3]: runfile('C:/Users/User/.spyder-py3/temp.py', wdir='C:/Users/User/.spyder-py3')
Reloaded modules: jupyter_client.session, zmq.eventloop, zmq.eventloop.ioloop, tornado.platform, tornado.platform.asyncio, tornado.gen, zmq.eventloop.zmqstream, jupyter_client.jsonutil, jupyter_client.adapter, spyder, spyder.pil_patch, PIL, PIL._version, PIL.Image, PIL.ImageMode, PIL.TiffTags, PIL._binary, PIL._util, PIL._imaging, cffi, cffi.api, cffi.lock, cffi.error, cffi.model
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\User\.spyder-py3\temp.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pandas_datareader import data

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas_datareader'
```

This happens not only with `pandas_datareader`, but also with `seaborn` and `plotly`. Besides that, I also get a name error:
`NameError: name 'data' is not defined`.

When I try to reinstall these packages using `pip` it says that they're already installed and working. What else can I do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No module named 'pandas\_datareader' in Jupyter (Anaconda) after I run pip3 install pandas\_datareader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55323996/no-module-named-pandas-datareader-in-jupyter-anaconda-after-i-run-pip3-insta)

Comment: Probably just means your `PYTHONPATH` isn't what you think it is..

Comment: maybe you have two Pythons installed and your `pip` install modules in one Python but your code runs on other Python. If you runs `python script` then you should try also `python -m pip install ...` and it should install in Python which you use to run script.